# Why are some questions highlighted in green?

Tags: support

Some of the questions are highlighted in green . What does that indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the questions with acepted answers.

Answer (score 4):

These questions are tagged with your favorite tags. Conversely, questions using tags on your ignore list are greyed out.